# C Pipe: Parent to read from child before child ends

Tags: c, fork, pipe

The code below shows how a child process can **write** to a **pipe** end and then how the parent process can **read** from the other end.
What I noticed after I experimented with the code is that only after the child process is **terminated** the parent will be able to **read** the data.

Is there a way to force the parent process to come to the foreground and read the data immediately after the child called **write()** ? And is there a way to read the data without terminating the child?

```
#include <stdio.h> /* For printf */
#include <string.h> /* For strlen */
#include <stdlib.h> /* For exit */

#define READ 0 /* Read end of pipe */
#define WRITE 1 /* Write end of pipe */
char *phrase = "This is a test phrase.";
main(){
    int pid, fd[2], bytes;
    char message[100];

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) { /* Create a pipe */
        perror("pipe"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) { /* Fork a child */
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    if (pid == 0) { /* Child, writer */
        close(fd[READ]); /* Close unused end */
        write(fd[WRITE], phrase, strlen(phrase)+1);
        close(fd[WRITE]); /* Close used end */
    } 
    else { /* Parent, reader */
        close(fd[WRITE]); /* Close unused end */
        bytes = read(fd[READ], message, sizeof(message));
        printf("Read %d bytes: %s\n", bytes, message);
        close(fd[READ]);  /* Close used end */
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want  that the parent should wait for the termination of the child? Because your observation that the parent reads only after the child terminates may not be correct.I think what you have observed is that you are not getting back the shell prompt after this program terminates.This can simply be solved, by making sure that the parent waits for the termination of the child by using the wait call.But if you want to ensure that the child terminates, only when it is sure that the parent has read the data, this also can be done. Can you pl. let me know what exactly is the requirement.

Comment: @Tanmoy What I want is for parent to read the data before child terminates. I also want the parent to read the data immediately after the child whites to the pipe.

Comment: I have explained some concepts in my answer. Pl. let me know if that helped.Pl. think of your 2nd requirement once more. In a multiprogramming environment, you may not have any portable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correct. Try to add the `sleep(120)` call just before closing the write end of pipe in the 'child' part and run your application.

Comment: kind of a long time to sleep, when all you need to do is yield the cpu, don't you think? How about simply calling sched_yield() [assuming running on a system that supports it, but whatever is similar on other systems]?

Comment: That long to give a time to the OP to type in `ps` and hit enter ))

Comment: You are right. Could you check another question I posted? I have the same problem as in this post but if I add sleep before closing the write end of pipe it does not read until child is terminated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657430/c-read-from-pipe-blocks-until-child-is-terminated

Answer (score 1):

The first can be done using some synchronisation techniques.*Means the child should wait till the parent reads data or here in your code the parent terminates. I have added a 2nd pipe to the code which is used for this synchronisation.*

The child after writing simply waits to read from that pipe and gets blocked in read.

The function read will return (0 here) only when the parent terminates, since now read in child will get the end of file notification, due to close of  the pipe's  write end in parent after parent's exit. 
(The write end will be automatically closed after the parent terminates. I have not added that explicitly)

Your 2nd requirement

```
I also want the parent to read the data immediately after the child whites to
the pipe.
```

Why do you think this is not happening? There should always be some minute time lag.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* For printf */
#include <string.h> /* For strlen */
#include <stdlib.h> /* For exit */

#define READ 0 /* Read end of pipe */
#define WRITE 1 /* Write end of pipe */
char *phrase = "This is a test phrase.";
main(){
  int pid, fd[2], bytes;
  char message[100];
  int fd1[2];
  char buffer[1];
  int ret;

  if (pipe(fd) == -1) { /* Create a pipe */
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (pipe(fd1) == -1) { /* Create a pipe */
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
  }
  if ((pid = fork()) == -1) { /* Fork a child */
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (pid == 0) { /* Child, writer */
    close(fd[READ]); /* Close unused end */
    close(fd1[WRITE]);/*Close write  end of the 2nd pipe*/
    write(fd[WRITE], phrase, strlen(phrase)+1);
    close(fd[WRITE]); /* Close used end */
    /*For synchronisation let the child try to
    read from the 2nd pipe. 
    The function read, will return 0 only when the
    parent terminates and in this we are
    not interested if at all anything read or not.
    The read statement below, will return only if the
    parent has terminated, thus ensures that the
    child terminates only after the parent*/
    ret = read(fd1[READ],buffer, 1);
  }

else { /* Parent, reader */
    close(fd[WRITE]); /* Close unused end */
    close(fd1[READ]); /*Close read end of the 2nd pipe*/
    bytes = read(fd[READ], message, sizeof(message));
    printf("Read %d bytes: %s\n", bytes, message);
    close(fd[READ]);  /* Close used end */

   }
}
```

Comment: This is a late comment but this code has brought me to more insight for my little program: how can i send data from a child to a parent of unknown length. This technique helped me a lot.  (my program is written in assembly language so I don't put it here because this is about C programming.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the fd[0]=0 and fd[1]=0

Answer (score 0):

following code demos that, after child write to pipe, parents could read pipe. no need for child process close pipe or terminates.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* For printf */
#include <string.h> /* For strlen */
#include <stdlib.h> /* For exit */

#define READ 0 /* Read end of pipe */
#define WRITE 1 /* Write end of pipe */
char *phrase = "This is a test phrase.";
main(){
    int pid, fd[2], bytes;
    char message[100];

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) { /* Create a pipe */
        perror("pipe"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) { /* Fork a child */
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(1); 
    }
    if (pid == 0) { /* Child, writer */
        close(fd[READ]); /* Close unused end */
        write(fd[WRITE], phrase, strlen(phrase)+1);
        sleep(10);
        close(fd[WRITE]); /* Close used end */
        sleep(20);
    } 
    else { /* Parent, reader */
        printf( "child ipd = %d\n\r", pid);
        close(fd[WRITE]); /* Close unused end */
        bytes = read(fd[READ], message, sizeof(message));
        printf("Read %d bytes: %s\n", bytes, message);
        close(fd[READ]);  /* Close used end */
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```