# Executing Multiple Pipes in a Loop

Tags: c, linux, shell, piping

I am *so* close to figuring out a program I have been writing for linux shell written in C.  I have been wanting to get this working for a while now, and I decided to pick it up again and have been tinkering with it for the past few weeks.

For the following code, keep in mind that the array called **arrayOfCommands** is dynamically filled.  My code fills the arrayOfCommands with the current command being run.  For the sake of my example, we will be running the command **ls -l | wc** and arrayOfCommands is filled with the following, depending on which time through the loop it is:

```
//Pass #1
arrayOfCommands[]= ("ls", "-l", NULL)

//Pass #2
arrayOfCommands[]= ("wc", NULL)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
//PIPING
int do_command(char **args, int pipes) {
    // pipes is the number of pipes in the command
    // (In our example, one)


    // The number of commands is one more than the
    // number of pipes (In our example, two)
    const int commands = pipes + 1;  //Ex: 2
    int i = 0;

    // Set up the pipes
    int pipefds[2*pipes];

    for(i = 0; i < pipes; i++){
        if(pipe(pipefds + i*2) < 0) {
            perror("Couldn't Pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    // Variables
    int pid;
    int status;
    char *str_ptr;

    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < commands; ++i) {

        // A magic function that updates arrayOfCommands with
        // the current command goes here.  It doesn't make 
        // sense in the context of the code, so just believe me! :)

        // Ex: The contents will be "ls -l" or "wc" depending on 
        // which time through the loop we are

        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0) {
            //if not last command
            if(i < commands){
                if(dup2(pipefds[j + 1], 1) < 0){
                    perror("dup2");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            //if not first command&& j!= 2*pipes
            if(j != 0 ){
                if(dup2(pipefds[j-2], 0) < 0){
                    perror("dup2");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            for(i = 0; i < 2*pipes; i++){
                    close(pipefds[i]);
            }

            // Should any of the below inputs be *arrayOfCommands or 
            // **arrayOfCommands or &arrayOfCommands?
            // I'm REALLY bad with pointers

            if( execvp(arrayOfCommands, arrayOfCommands) < 0 ){
                    perror(arrayOfCommands);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else if(pid < 0){
            perror("error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        j+=2;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 2 * pipes; i++){
        close(pipefds[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < pipes + 1; i++){
    }
        wait(&status);
}
```

When I run this, I get a couple of errors:

- dup2: Bad file descriptor
- ls: |: No such file or directory
- ls: wc: No such file or directory

Could someone help me figure out the following two things:

1. Why am I getting these errors?
2. In the execvp function, what kinds if pointers am I looking for?  **arrayOfCommands was initialized as a char *arrayOfArgs[]**

Comment: Deja vu. Please, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657430/c-read-from-pipe-blocks-until-child-is-terminated/12661629#12661629 then try to follow the described procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing:

```
//if not last command
if(i < commands)
```

should be

```
if(i < commands -1)
```

since `i`goes from `0` to `commands -1`
that should solve dup2: Bad file descriptor

ls: |: No such file or directory

ls: wc: No such file or directory

are caused by malformed  `arrayOfCommands`. It has to be initialized by

```
char * arrayOfCommands[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
```

and

```
char * arrayOfCommands[] = {"wc", NULL};
```

respectively and invoked via `execvp(arrayOfCommands[0], arrayOfCommands)`

essentially `arrayOfCommands` has to be of the same format that your argument vector (typically `argv`) of an `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.